# Java can not connect to Server Socket

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I have a multi threaded Server Socket running on 1 computer running as follows:

```
static void createServer() throws IOException {
    //use this ip for other user
    System.out.println(InetAddress.getLocalHost());
    // establish server socket
    try {
        ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(8888);

        while (true) {
            Socket incoming = s.accept();
            Runnable r = new ThreadedEchoHandler(incoming, map);
            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.start();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Then from another computer I try to connect to the Server(using the ip from first computer 192.168.162.1) as follows:

```
public void registerCmnd(Scanner keys) throws IOException {
    InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("first computer ip");
    try (Socket s = new Socket(ip, 8888)) {
        .....
        .....
   }

}
```

I am getting a java.net.ConnectException.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at User.registerCmnd(User.java:45)
at User.main(User.java:28)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Show us the stacktrace.  And also the IP addresses being used, client and server side.

Comment: Is the connection being blocked by a firewall on one or the other machine?

Comment: I turned off all firewalls on both machines

Comment: Can you run the server and client on the same machine? Also, maybe print out the IP address retrieved from `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` and `InetAddress.getByName` and confirm they are the same.

Comment: Show us the IP addresses please.  It could be important.

Comment: IP address returned from InetAddress.getLocalHost() is 192.168.162.1

Comment: @mark watson. When I run the server and client on the same machine I do not have any issues

Comment: And what IP address are you using on the client side?  And what is the client's IP address.

Comment: I am using the same ip address on the client side when I attempt to connect to the server: try (Socket s = new Socket(ip, 8888).                                        The clients ip is 192.168.1.105

Comment: Those IPs (192.168.1.105 and 192.168.162.1) are most likely on different subnets.  My bet is that it is routing problem.

Comment: @Stephen c so how can I fix this?

Comment: Set up routing.  This is NOT a StackOverflow problem.  Search the Q&As on SuperUser, then ask a question if you can't find anything. Or check the vendor support channels for your OS or your WiFi router for information about configuring WiFi networks and routing.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like the problem is in the code itself.

There are a number of possible causes for this, including

- A firewall, on the client, the server, a hypervisor stack, or the network is blocking access.
- You are using the wrong IP address for the server on the client
- You are using the wrong server port number on the client (not in this case)
- You are using an IP address that isn't routed from the client to the server.  For example, if the server's IP is a private address, and the client is on a different network.
- Someone has misconfigured the packet forwarding (e.g. iptables) or routing (e.g. routed, etc) on the client or server.  Or somewhere else.

---

If I were you, I would see whether one computer can PING the other and vice-versa.  If that fails, then check the routing tables.  Note that this is *most likely* a network configuration problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: I pinged the server from the client computer: Packets: sent = 4, Recieved=1

Answer (score 0):

You either have the wrong ip, the port is not forwarded, or both. also make sure to run the server first.

Comment: The server is running. I get the ip of the first machine using InetAddres.getLocalHost() method.

Comment: What is port forwarding?

Comment: If a computer wants to connect from a different network you tell your router to connect that computer to you

Comment: If you are just doing at home stuff you dont need this

Comment: Both computers are on the same wifi connection

Comment: OK go on the server computer open command prompt and type ipconfig, copy the address labeled ipv4 then pass that to the socket constructor on the client